# syntax error unexpected toke in if statement in js

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am receiving a syntax error with unexpected token < at line 14 when i try to run this script in my browser. What i am trying to do is open my classes 5 minutes before class and still open when ran all the way up to 5 minutes before the next class.

```
<script>
//Current time
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getTime();

//Time checker
if(time >= 7:55 && < 8:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyMjc3NTE0MzEw');
}
if(time >= 8:55 && < 9:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTE1MjA4MzM5MDgz');
}
if(time >= 9:55 && < 10:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyMjk4MzAxMjYx');
}
if(time >= 10:55 && < 11:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIzMjMyNzU4ODk2');
}
if(time >= 11:55 && < 12:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIzMTkzMjU1MjAx');
}
if(time >= 12:55 && < 13:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyMjk4MzAxMjQx');
}
if(time >= 13:55 && < 14:55){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyNDk3Mjk5NDQ2');
}
if(time >= 14:55 && <= 15:00){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyNjk1NTQxMzYw');
}
</script>
```

Comment: `7:55` is not valid; it just doesn't work that way. For one thing, `.getTime()` gets you the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC, not a time-of-day.

Comment: And this isn't valid either: `&& < 8:55`

Comment: Also, you have to specify both sides of your comparison in the if clauses: "if ((time > 3600000) && (time < 7200000))"

Comment: Use `getHours()` and `getMinutes()`, convert that to minutes since midnight, then compare that with your ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date.getTime()` doesn't return the time of day. If you want the time of day, use `date.getHours()` and `date.getMinutes()`. You can then convert this to the number of minutes since midnight, which you can use to tell if the time is within your specific ranges.

```js
//Current time
var date = new Date();
var time = 60 * date.getHours() + date.getMinutes();

//Time checker
if(time >= (7 * 60 + 55) && time < (8 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyMjc3NTE0MzEw');
}
if(time >= (8 * 60 + 55) && time < (9 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTE1MjA4MzM5MDgz');
}
if(time >= (9 * 60 + 55) && time < (10 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyMjk4MzAxMjYx');
}
if(time >= (10 * 60 + 55) && time < (11 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIzMjMyNzU4ODk2');
}
if(time >= (11 * 60 + 55) && time < (12 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIzMTkzMjU1MjAx');
}
if(time >= (12 * 60 + 55) && time < (13 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyMjk4MzAxMjQx');
}
if(time >= (13 * 60 + 55) && time < (14 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyNDk3Mjk5NDQ2');
}
if(time >= (14 * 60 + 55) && time < (15 * 60 + 55)){
    window.open('https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIyNjk1NTQxMzYw');
}
```

Comment: im new to javascript, do you mind explaining what the * and 60 is for

Comment: `*` is multiplication. 60 is the number of minutes in an hour.

Comment: Multiply the hour by 60 to get the number of minutes since midnight. Simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The getTime() will give you the number of millisecond.
Try date.getHours() instead.
Remember to pass the argument to get more specific value